# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Tuesday 7 Feb 21:00 UTC / 4pm EST

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 7th at 21:00 UTC / 4:00pm EST

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=07&year=2012&hour=21&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/268/ask-ubuntu-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

**[participate here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/268/ask-ubuntu-town-hall-chat)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 6th-8th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=askubuntu.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: The town hall chat happens at 5 am my time. Highly unlikely that I would make it. Good luck to everyone who is participating!

Comment: @jokerdino You can reply to the questions after the event if you can't make it.